# Connect to internet in recovery mode?

Tags: networking, 17.04, recovery-mode

I had a few problems with my Ubuntu and in order to fix them, I needed to boot into recovery mode and update everything, well I am in recovery mode but how do I connect to the internet? (I am wanting to connect to a Wireless network with WPA security OR my mobile hotspot connected via USB cable)

Comment: IICR there's an option to enable networking in the menu that pops up after you enter recovery mode

Comment: Once I click that, I choose yes to put it in read/write mode and it does a few things then brings me back to the menu but I'm still not connected to the network.

Comment: I checked System Summary and it says IP Configured but when I run apt update I get errors saying I can't resolve anything, maybe a DNS problem?

Comment: Have you previously connected to the Wi-Fi network you're trying to use?

Comment: Yes, it used to automatically connect.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

Answer (score 11):

*I deleted the original answer and posted it on this question.  I'll flag the duplicate.*

Ping an external server to determine if the Internet is available.

From the terminal, type: `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`

If you get a ping reply, it means your internet is live. This shows that the issue is with DNS settings.

You can add a temporary DNS server like this: `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf`

If you do not get a reply from the ping, then the issue is with your local network.

Comment: how does this help me enable my connection?

Comment: @Xerus - It doesn't.  The OP was not asking about how to enable the connection.  Your issue is different, please consider starting a new question.  Thanks

Comment: thanks alot @ThatGuy this worked perfectly for me

Comment: worked like magic